# Prolog what's the difference between \+ and \=

Tags: prolog, logical-operators

What is the difference \= and \+?

because

```
?- 15\=14.
?- \+ 15=14.<--- this gives an error while the above does not.
```

Why?Aren't they the same?

Edit: here's the error:

```
Compiling the file:
D:\Program Files\Strawberry Prolog Beta\Games\WarCraft.pro
Warning 4: The string \+ is not an operator. (line 1, before the first clause)
Error 16: Instead of the integer 15 what is expected here is something like an infix operator or a full stop. (line 1, before the first clause)
1 error, 1 warning.
```

Also I'm using Strawberry prolog I also tried it on SWI prolog still the same.

Comment: Both work fine for me in SWI-Prolog (succeeding with `true.`). What Prolog are you using? What is the error message? Please edit the question to add this information.

Comment: Probably an operator precedence issue. Try `\+ (15=14).` Otherwise, it thinks you're trying to do `\+ 15` followed by `= 14` which would not make syntactic sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are putting queries into Prolog source files. That is not where they should go:

- *predicate definitions* go into Prolog source files
- *queries* are typed into the interactive Prolog toplevel

Try running the SWI-Prolog program *without an input file*. You should get a window with some informational messages about the SWI-Prolog version and then a prompt `?-`. That is the toplevel. Try typing your query there. All queries should go there.

I don't know about Strawberry Prolog, but I suspect it's the same there.

Comment: You were of big help and now I know that strawberry prolog is bad I convinced myself.